# Erratic gmail OAuth2 authentication with MailKit and Google APIs

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, mailkit, chilkat-email

The MailKit and Google API C# code below was written to authenticate gmail access tokens in my Win10 desktop app.  However, the call to client.AuthenticateAsync usually, but not always, fails and indicates an incorrect user ID and password.

I've compared the client credentials during failed attempts with those during successful attempts and they are identical.  I've also checked the gmail account I am using to see if it wants me to verify that it is indeed me that is attempting the authentication, but it says everything is okay.  The same behavior occurs with a different set of credentials as well as with a different gmail email account.

I've also written a Chilkat Software version that doesn't use MailKit or the Google APIs.  It uses exactly the same credentials and access tokens and it never fails, even when MailKit/Google API version is complaining about erroneous user ids and passwords.  I'd like to use MailKit instead simply because it is free and Chilkat isn't.

I've had the same issues with the MailKit version regardless of which version of .NET I've tried (4.8.1, 6, and 8), but the Chilkat version always works with all of them.  Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated.

```
  static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
  {
     string from = $"sample@gmail.com";
     string path = @"ClientCredentials.json";
     string[] scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com/" };
     string accessToken = @"";

     try
     {
        var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.FromFile(path).Secrets,
            scopes,
            mailbox,
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), true));

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
           client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);

           var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(from, credential.Token.AccessToken);
           accessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;
           await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);

           if (!client.IsAuthenticated)
           {
              // Refresh the access token
              if (credential.Token.IsStale)
              {
                 await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
                 accessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;

                 oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(from, accessToken);
                 await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
              }
           }
           client.Disconnect(true);
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}");
     }
  }
```

Comment: Can I see the full error message?   [How I fixed fix for SMTP username and password not accepted error.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI)

Comment: @Linda Lawton  Below is the message.  When I go to the provided link I find nothing wrong:

Error details: 535: 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to
5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials s123-20020a632c81000000b005ca5619a764sm6180068pgs.11 - gsmtp
   at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.AuthenticateAsync(SaslMechanism mechanism, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at OAuth2_Authorization.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\VS Programs\MailKit Examples\OAuth2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried debugging your code, but I can spot a few problems just looking at it:

```
var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(from, credential.Token.AccessToken);
accessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;
await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);

if (!client.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // Refresh the access token
    if (credential.Token.IsStale)
    {
        await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        accessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;

        oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(from, accessToken);
        await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
    }
}
```

The exception you are getting is on the above `await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);`

You then check if authentication was successful to see if you need to refresh your auth token, but control flow never reaches that if-statement because an AuthenticationException was thrown, so it never refreshes the token or tries to authenticate a second time.

Change your code to this:

```
// Refresh the access token if it is stale
if (credential.Token.IsStale)
{
    await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
}

var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(from, credential.Token.AccessToken);
await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
```

Now it'll probably work.

Comment: #jstedfast, Yes that was the problem, and it was then obvious that the extra block that tested for authentication was not needed because it would never be reached!  You just saved me a lot of time and frustration :-)  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Username and Password not accepted

Is the standard error message when you are trying to connect to Googles SMPT server and are trying to use the users actual google password.

As of May 30 2022 google has removed the less secure apps option. There is no way to turn this on as it no longer exists.

You have two options

1. Enable 2fa on your google account and create an [apps password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) and use that in place of your true password in your code.
2. switch to using Xoauth2.

[Quick fix for SMTP username and password not accepted error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI)

Comment: I am not attempting to use the userID and password in the code I previously provided.  It instead uses the OAuth2 credentials I obtained for my Google Cloud project on their website.  I have several other project credentials I've also tried and the erratic behavior is the same with all of them.  It's basically a coin toss - sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.  The Chilkcat version works perfectly on all projects all the time, but I'd like to use a free library instead.

Comment: #Linda, The Google Cloud projects whose OAuth2 credentials I am using in my code are published but not verified by Google.  However, the OAuth Consent Screen for them states that verification is not required.  Is it possible that they actually do need to be verified for my OAuth2 code to work consistently when using those credentials?

Comment: Its only required if you are going to have others use your application, if this is single users its not required Ignore that message.  I have tried to get them to change it they say its working as intended